# Translating Python into Scheme/Racket

Tags: python-2.7, scheme, lisp, racket

I'm currently trying to translate this python 2 code:

```
import math

def worstCaseArrayOfSize(n):
    if n == 1:
        return [1]
    else:
        top = worstCaseArrayOfSize(int(math.floor(float(n) / 2)))
        bottom = worstCaseArrayOfSize(int(math.ceil(float(n) / 2)))
        return map(lambda x: x * 2, top) + map(lambda x: x * 2 - 1, bottom)
```

into racket/scheme code, and having a difficult time.

This is what I have so far:

```
(define (msortWorstCase n)
  (cond
    [(equal? 1 n) 1]
    [else (let* ([top (msortWorstCase(floor (/ n 2)))] [bottom (msortWorstCase (ceiling (/ n 2)))]) 

(append (map (lambda (x) (* x 2)) (list top)) (map (lambda (x) (- (* x 2) 1)) (list bottom))))]
    )
  )
```

Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong with this?

I am getting the following error:

```
*: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: '(2 1)
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
```

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your recursion is making lists of lists of lists of lists... with `(list top)` and `(list bottom)`.

You should do the same thing in Racket as you did in Python; the base case should be a one-element list, and you should not wrap the results in lists in the recursive case.

```
(define (msortWorstCase n)
  (cond
    [(equal? 1 n) '(1)]
    [else (let* ([top (msortWorstCase(floor (/ n 2)))] 
                 [bottom (msortWorstCase (ceiling (/ n 2)))]) 
             (append (map (lambda (x) (* x 2)) top) 
                     (map (lambda (x) (- (* x 2) 1)) bottom)))]))
```